# getReturnValue returns undefined

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, custom-object, lightning

In my Lightning Component, I'm doing a very simple call to server side action which is executed when you click on a button, here's an example:

```
  getCustomObjects: function(component) {
    var action = component.get('c.getCustomObjects');

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
            console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            component.set('v.CustomObjects', response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
```

I then have an APEX controller, that does a simple query to return all Custom Objects in our records. Like below:

```
public with sharing class CustomObjectController {

  @AuraEnabled
  public static List getCustomObjects() {
      List<CustomObject__c> objects = [SELECT Id, object_name__c FROM CustomObject__c];

    return objects;
  }
}
```

When I press the button to execute the ***getCustomObjects*** method, response.getReturnValue() returns undefined and it seems it gets stuck in an infinite loop and then crashes with the error below:

[image]

My example is based from this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_records.htm) and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what checks I have to do to see why this is happening. Performing the query in the Developer Console returns all the records that I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the name of the variables here .Be always careful with naming your actions on the server and the client side .

```
getCustomObjects: function(component) {
   var action = component.get('c.getCustomObjects');
```

So your above code your actions name is **getCustomObjects** and your JS controller name is also **getCustomObjects** .

This will create an internal recursion leading to calling server side actions again and again and setting the attribute value clearly hitting the browser stack size .

Change the name of the controller at client site to this

```
getClientCustomObjects: function(component) {
   var action = component.get('c.getCustomObjects');
```

The recursion can happen in javascript  as well and below is a sample code that can cause stack hit .The similar thing is happening in this scenario

```
(function a() {
    a();
 })();//This can cause stack size exception
```

Comment: Thank you, Mohith. That worked. That seems like a gotcha to me. I'm not sure if I have read this somewhere and just forget or maybe it's something that hasn't been explained in the docs.

Comment: Its not in docs and somethings come by experience and using salesforce stackexchange website :) .Glad you posted and glad i tried and figured the root cause

Comment: Mohit, when you are referring heap size are referring apex heap size?

Comment: No the browser stack and not the apex .

Comment: Ok.But I don't think the problem is due to hitting heap size in the browser, it's primarily due to client side controller function being stacked up and called infinitely(recursively as you mentioned) which inturn hits the browser call stack limit.

Comment: Heap and stack in client language like JS mean same .I have added more explanation to make the answer precise .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47422/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-praveen).

Comment: Note that this is mentioned currently in the doc under https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm . ==Use unique names for client-side and server-side actions in a component. A JavaScript function (client-side action) with the same name as a server-side action (Apex method) can lead to hard-to-debug issues.== We're very open to input if you have suggestions for improving this or other places where this message would be helpful.

Comment: @MarkL It says hard to debug but does not mention what effect it can do